# Sub route in @Url.Action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I need help with sub route in asp.net mvc. I need this route

```
Home/Index/6/Person/Index/8
```

In my RouteConfig i have this

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Prueba",
    url: "Home/Index/{id}/Person/{action}/{personId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Person", action = "Index", PersonId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

If I put this route `Home/Index/6/Person/Index/8` in URL Browser works, but I need the link

I don´t know how created this route with `@Url.Action(Action, Controller, new{ id=Value })`

Comment: Syntax: @Url.Action("Action Name","ControllerName",new {parameterName="parameterValue"})
In your case:

@Url.Action("Index","Person",new {id="6",personId="8"})

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Url.RouteUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl(v=vs.118).aspx) or [Html.RouteLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink(v=vs.118).aspx) methods

For example

```
@Html.RouteLink("Click me", "Prueba", new { id = 1, personId = 3 })
```

and

```
@Url.RouteUrl("Prueba", new { id = 1, personId = 3 })
```

If you want to specify a different action method in the route, then it would be for example `new { id = 1, personId = 3, action = "Edit" }`

Comment: Note that the `personId` argument is not required to match the route.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Url.Action("Index","Person",new {id="6",personId="8"})`

This will generate the required string, however it will pick the first route matching the criteria.

Syntax: `@Url.Action("Action Name","ControllerName",new {parameterName="parameterValue"})`

Reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Action%28System.String,System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary%29